# ID request - larvae on potato plants

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Several of these were on my potato plants in Washington state, USA. This one about 7mm in length, some were a bit larger. They were moving in an inchworm-like fashion, but only by touch - I don't think they have eyes.
[image: isopropanol preserved specimen]

This specimen was photographed after placing in isopropyl alcohol, which changed the color (it was almost white while alive) and the shape somewhat.

Comment: This larvae doesn't seem to match the common pests of potatoes. It is possible this larvae has been infected by a fungi and so is distorted in shape and colour.

Comment: @SergiiDymchenko — In the future please [edit] your post rather than putting important information into comments. Not everyone will read comments and they are also ephemeral, so they should only be used to discuss how to improve a post. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One notorious pest of potato plants are [cutworms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutworm). Unfortunately due to the the discoloration of the species I am not able to identify for sure which species of cutworm it is.

Cutworms attack a wide host of plants (more info [here](https://plantvillage.psu.edu/topics/potato/infos)). According to that same website, the main ways to avoid the damage these larvae can cause are to:

> Remove all plant residue from soil after harvest or at least two weeks before planting...

> ... plastic or foil collars fitted around plant stems to cover the bottom 3 inches above the soil line and extending a couple of inches into the soil can prevent larvae severing plants; hand-pick larvae after dark; spread diatomaceous earth around the base of the plants (this creates a sharp barrier that will cut the insects if they try and crawl over it); apply appropriate insecticides to infested areas of garden or field if not growing organically

These larvae come from a large variety of insects so don't associate them too quickly with one insect or another (many websites associate them with moths but that is not always necessarily accurate).

Here's a [source](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/insects/get-rid-cutworms.htm) that elaborates a bit more on how to treat them plus [another source](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/pesticides/using-pesticides-safely.htm) for how to use pesticides in a garden safely (if no other option is convenient).